# Can the adverb "perfectly" modify the verb "to be"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

> Such students may be perfectly at home with the language of an ode or a classical play, [...] [[Source]](https://archive.org/details/teachingforeignl0000rive_b8w7/page/199/mode/1up?q=perfectly&view=theater)

In a formal written language, isn't it grammatically incorrect to use, instead of an adjective, the adverb "perfectly" in this sentence?

In other words, based on a structure similar to the one used in that book which explains the situation of learners of English, is it correct to write: "I may be perfectly at the university with research tools, yet I find myself unable to effectively use them in real life situations" or "I am at the university with research tools perfectly, ..."

Is it possible to generalize and write: "I was closely to the cafeteria when I received the notification of your email."?

Keywords: "to be" + adverb - [adjective(s) || adverb || {"other verb" + ing}]

Comment: _Perfectly_ modifies _at home_.

Comment: ***I'm perfectly** happy with your example*. Why do you think there might be a problem with "being perfectly X"?

Comment: To me, ***at home*** and ***happy*** both look like adjectives describing a person's current state. But as a native speaker I don't have to concern myself with exactly what "adjective" means - I just know I don't see any difference between *I feel perfectly happy here* and *I feel perfectly at home here*. If you're working to a set of definitions within which ***at home*** is *not* adjectival, perhaps you need to clarify that.

Comment: Oh - do you mean your problem turns on a supposed distinction between "adjective" and "adverb"? I know approximately what those words mean, but I don't really care, and I don't consciously use any such categorization to decide how to phrase things. According to my understanding, *He speaks **in agreement** with me* looks adverbial, but *I am **in agreement*** looks adjectival. I dunno - maybe the fact that you can be *a happy man* but not *an in agreement man* is relevant.

Comment: @SvenYargs, In fact, it asked only whether "I'm perfectly at home..." makes sense, as I'm familiar with sentences where adjectives are used after "to be"...  "I'm perfectly at the university with the research tools", from my perspective, as non-native speaker as I depend mainly on grammar references, is not grammatically correct, is it? And thus, according to me, doesn't make sense, does it? I actually didn't perceive "at home with", which implies in its deducible meaning two adjectives, as an idiom.

Comment: "At home" in this context means "familiar, well-informed", but "to the cafeteria" only has the literal meaning, hence the difference in the use of the adverb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm so sorry for having misunderstood you, It's obvious that your intention is good, but using words such as "your problem", "supposed" in an educational situation (teaching/learning) are, here in our culture, considered very harsh (though they may be normal in other cultures in any context)... And thus made me feel that I'm perceived as subjectively determined to never agree... Please accept my apologies.

Comment: No worries (I could have phrased things better myself! :) In fact, it seems to me now that the only reason you didn't understand the cited sentence is because you didn't know the idiomatic sense of ***at home = comfortable, familiar*** (the sentence doesn't make sense if you try to apply the *literal* meaning ***at home = at one's normal place of residence***). So my question about adjectives / adverbs wasn't relevant anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thank you so much, I really appreciate your kindness and support, in fact your statements are informative to me as a learner of English and help me to improve my use/usage skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb that *perfectly* is modifying here is actually a phrasal one: *to be [at home with](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/at%20home%20with)*. That means the author's wording is perfectly grammatical; whether or not one can split a phrasal verb is a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: Thank you @Heartspring. Can you please suggest a clear reformulation of the given sentence. The example you provided includes the adjective "grammatical".

Comment: Some particle multi-word verbs are optionally separable (for non-pronoun NPs) ('They **brought Ø** the substitute **Ø**'; **Ø** a slot for '**on**'), some are obligatorily separable ('You really **had** Jim **on**'), and some inseparable ('We **came by** a great deli in Macclesfield').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But "may be at home with" isn't  a phrasal verb. It is just "may be" plus an idiomatic adjectival PP compliment modified by the adverb.

Comment: A big thanks for all of you. As cited in the answer, "at home with" is, unexpectedly, an idiom which implies the adjective "comfortable". The suggested formulation is "Such students may be perfectly comfortable about using the language of an ode or a classical play..."

Comment: @Phil Sweet That's how I'd analyse it, but verbo-nominal multi word verbs are recognised. Claridge (In 'Multi-word Verbs in Early Modern English ...'), who I see as a leading authority here, gives an overview of terminology, and lists the subset of verbo-nominal multi-word verbs such as 'put an end to' (though 'an ent to' is itself a fixed expression). // This example clearly isn't a particle MWV, and I was addressing 'whether or not one can split a phrasal verb is a matter of style, not grammar' which doubtless refers to all classes of MWVs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'Verbo-nominal multi-word verbs'? Yes, well ...! I hope you're not suggesting that some prepositional VPs are headed by 'multi-word verbs'.

Comment: I'm stating that there is divided opinion on the cohesiveness of some verbo-nominal constructions (often with a transitivising particle) such as 'take cover'; 'make fun of'. Analysis can depend on which tests you choose to apply.